# Android Sticky Header: black underline on Scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a sticky header listView for my app. When i scroll down, the header view at the top will have a black underline (which is below the date) and looks very strange. But the underline will disappear when you scroll back to the top. I tried the below codes but still not successful.

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
listView.setOverscrollHeader(null);
listView.setFadingEdgeLength(0);
listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

How would i remove that underline? Thanks in advance and great if anyone would share the solutions with me.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the black shadow?

Comment: Did you check my asnwer? if my answer worked mark it as a correct :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "black shadow", you have to do this with :

```
listView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

or

```
android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
android:overScrollMode="never"
```